# Custom array_filter using callback

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of associative arrays as follow.

```
$list = array(
  array("animal" => 0, "color" => 0, "coins" => 10),
  array("animal" => 0, "color" => 1, "coins" => 20),
  array("animal" => 0, "color" => 2, "coins" => 10),
  array("animal" => 1, "color" => 0, "coins" => 55),
  array("animal" => 1, "color" => 1, "coins" => 25),
  array("animal" => 1, "color" => 2, "coins" => 10)
);
```

I would like to filter the array to remain only when "coins" < 30, so I tried.

```
function less_than_10($var) {
  return ($var < 30);
}

array_filter($list, "less_then_10");
```

But it was not working the way i expected, please guide how to filter by specifying the filtered key of the array.

Comment: You have a typo there.. it should be `less_than_10`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three important points to make:

- You have a multi-dimensional array, so you will need to change `return ($var < 30);` to `return ($var['coins'] < 30);`.
- `array_filter()` *returns* the array. You will have to store the return value to a variable in order to be able to use it later.
- You have a typo in your callback function `less_then_10` should be `less_than_10`.

Modified code:

```
function less_than_30($arr) {
    return ($arr['coins'] < 30);
}

$result = array_filter($list, "less_than_30");
print_r($result);
```

If the callback function is only ever used once, you can just make it into an anonymous function, like so:

```
$result = array_filter($list, function ($arr) {
    return ($arr['coins'] < 30);
});
```

Much cleaner, right? However, right now this function is a bit pointless as you can't check for values other than 30. You can expand its functionality using a `use` block:

```
$min = 10; // Change this value as necessary

$result = array_filter($list, function ($arr) use ($min) {
    return ($arr['coins'] < $min);
});
```

Comment: Great answer. I was about to add an example of `use` but I saw you did it and didn't wanna copy :P.

Comment: You've just covered everything including my future questions, thanks :P

Answer (score 4):

You can do that using a [closure](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) (or anonymous functions) in PHP >= 5.3.

```
$list = array_filter($list, function($a) {
    return $a['coins'] < 30;
});
```

Also, as Shankar Damodaran said in his comment, you *do* have a typo in your function name when calling `array_filter()`.

[Here is a great explanation for closures in PHP 5.3](http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2010/10/08/lambda-functions-and-closures-in-php-5-3/).

Comment: For reference, though anonymous functions are really good for this, using a regular function would work too.  The real fix is in what the filter function is comparing, and what's done with the return value from `array_filter`.

Comment: +1: This is correct. But I'm not really sure whether the OP wants to get sub-arrays that have coin values less than 30 or 10.

Comment: You are both right.. Thanks for the input!  Hey it's a win win win because all three of us are right! :)